# How can I implement perspective change with python?

Tags: python, image

I am writing a Python program that has an image processing block. I need to change the perspective of an image using Python, how can I do that?

Example:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPaFG.png)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5sY4.png)

I tried using libraries
numpy, OpenCV or PIL (Python Imaging Library)

Comment: Manually select a set of 4 points in the source image, and the matching 4 points in the destination image. Execute `M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pt1,pts2)` then execute `dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,(cols, rows))`. There are few tutorials that shows the process. Check the [following](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/opencv-perspective-transformation-9edffefb2143) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the sample code and before and after images.
I used a percentage of images to change the perspective.
You can play with the dst_points and percentage as you like.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def change_perspective(image, src_points, dst_points):
    # Define the transformation matrix
    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src_points, dst_points)

    # Apply the perspective transformation
    transformed_image = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]))

    return transformed_image

# Load the image
image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')

# Define the source and destination points for perspective transformation
src_points = np.float32([[0, 0], [image.shape[1] - 1, 0], [0, image.shape[0] - 1], [image.shape[1] - 1, image.shape[0] - 1]])

# Specify the percentage reduction of the height (e.g., 20% reduction)
height_reduction_percentage = 20
reduction_pixels = int(image.shape[0] * (height_reduction_percentage / 100))

# Adjust destination points for the desired transformation
dst_points = np.float32([[0, 0], [image.shape[1] - 1, reduction_pixels], [0, image.shape[0] - 1], [image.shape[1] - 1, image.shape[0] - 1 - reduction_pixels]])


# Change the perspective of the image
transformed_image = change_perspective(image, src_points, dst_points)

# Display the original and transformed images
cv2.imshow('Original Image', image)
cv2.imshow('Transformed Image', transformed_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Before
[image]

After
[image]